# ¿Cómo puedo hacer una conexión con JAVA hacia un SMPPSim?

Tags: java, sms

Estoy intentando crear una aplicación que envíe SMS.

Estuve averiguando y es necesario un SMPP y un ESME (Creo que es la aplicacion que uno crea).

Quiero inicialmente hacer una conexión simple al servidor SMPPSim que tengo levantado de forma local en mi PC mediante java.

Esta es mi clase que debería hacer una conexión al servidor:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Conex {
   final String HOST = "localhost";
   final int PUERTO=5000;
   static Socket sc;
   static DataOutputStream mensaje;
   DataInputStream entrada;
   public static void main(String[] args){
       System.out.println("inicio");
       try{
          sc = new Socket( "127.0.0.1" , 2776 );
          mensaje = new DataOutputStream(sc.getOutputStream());
          mensaje.writeUTF("hola que tal!!");
          sc.close();
      }catch(Exception e ){
          System.out.println("Error: "+e.getMessage());
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué errores te da la implementación actual? Dale a [edit] para añadir más detalles

Comment: @fedorqui Me sales esto 
`Error: Connection refused: connect`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No coincido en que para enviar SMS sea es necesario un SMPP y un ESME. De hecho, ese es el camino más complicado para hacerlo. Un ESME al final se tiene que conectar con un SMSC, normalmente mediante SMPP. SMPP es un protocolo entre Operadores de Red y Proveedores de contenido. Para hacer el envío real sería necesario contar con credenciales para el acceso y SMPPSim no deja de ser un simulador para probar el código, pero no permite el envío a celulares reales.

En el código que pones, estás intentando conectar con el servidor SMPPSim que dices haber levantado, pero un simple DataOutputStream sólo envía el texto por el socket abierto, mientras que el protocolo SMPP requiere el establecimiento de una conexión (Bind) con credenciales de acceso siguiendo un determinado protocolo de comunicación, de ahí que probablemente el servidor esté rechazando directamente la conexión.

Para poder establecer la conexión con SMPPSim, más que una conexión directa a través de un socket, lo que habría que hacer para no complicarse la vida con los detalles del protocolo SMPP es utilizar alguna librería que implemente este protocolo. [OpenSmpp](https://github.com/OpenSmpp/opensmpp) es una buena solución.

Para no desviar el tema de esta pregunta no lo incluiré en mi respuesta aquí, pero si lo que estás buscando es un método sencillo para enviar SMS desde java, pregunta específicamente por ello y estaré encantado de responder.

Comment: Para que sea bien recibida la respuesta agrega un ejemplo con código que tenga un [mcve], te invito a leer [answer]

Comment: Hola!, Ya tengo el OPENSMPP sin embargo no puedo establecer conexión por el largo de caracteres que solicita para la contraseña. Estuve buscando y no encuentro la forma de cambiar el largo permitido para la contraseña. El máximo es 7 y la contraseña que me brindaron es de 12. Alguna recomendación?